# storyboard views not resizing correctly

Tags: uiview, resize, storyboard

I'm using the storyboard using Xcode 4.5. I've put a UIContainerView into a (custom, and not the initial) view controller, then put three UIViews into the container view. I've used dynamic resizing to position the three views. All three fill the screen horizontally. One stays at the top of the screen with a fixed height, one stays at the bottom with a fixed height, and the third view (a subclass of UIView that customizes drawRect) fills the space between the two other views.

Everything looks fine in Storyboard, even when I switch to iPhone 5 size and back. However, when I run the app in the simulator and navigate to that view controller, I only see the middle view filling the screen. No sight of the other two. I switched the middle view back to a UIView, and the same problem occurs. I checked the entering segue, and it is to the view controller, not a specific view.

To be clear, this was all created using storyboard, NOT programmatically.

Comment: I'think you are mistaking the usage of UIContainerView. Remove them and only use UIViews

Answer (score 0):

1. Default Stack View pin 0 to all side of mainView.
2. Add 3 children View to Stack View
3. 1 and 3  children - height constraint = 150

[image]